# perl get array value not memory address

Tags: arrays, perl

Here is the code

```
 open IN, '</root/Desktop/out.txt' or die "Cannot open file : $!";
 while (<IN>) {
 chomp $_;
 $seq_no= $_;
 my @this_seq=();
 if($seq_no=~ m/^complement\(/){
 push(@this_seq,1);
 $seq_no=~ s/complement\(//g;
 if($seq_no=~ m/^order/){
 push(@this_seq,2);
 $seq_no=~ s/order//g;
 $seq_no=~ s/\(//g;
 $seq_no=~ s/\)//g;
 #my @temp = split(/,/, $seq_no);
 push @this_seq,$seq_no;
 print "@this_seq    \n";
}

}
else
{
 $seq_no=~ s/\(//g;
 $seq_no=~ s/\)//g;
 push @this_seq,$seq_no;
#print "@this_seq \n";
 }
 push @sequence,\@this_seq;
 }
 print @sequence;
```

The out file is

```
complement(order(1843..1881,1923..2001,2065..2147, 2216..2277,2330..2468))  
773..1447
```

But when i print @sequence it just get

```
ARRAY(0x119adb8)ARRAY(0x117e6b0)
```

I have already add \@this_seq when push into array, but it still shows memory address, can anyone tell me how to change it to shows array content.

Comment: Use `while( my $seq_no = <IN> ){ chomp $seq_no; ...` since you don't otherwise use `$_`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are doing this:

```
push @sequence,\@this_seq;
```

you are pushing a reference to @this_seq into @sequence, so at the end @sequence contains two references to two separate arrays. If that is what you intended then you can print it out like this:

```
foreach my $seq (@sequence) {
    print join(',', @$seq),"\n";
}
```

That will print the contents of the two arrays on two separate lines. The outer loop iterates through the array references, the 'join' statement joins together the contents of each of the array refs (note that @$seq de-references the array reference contained in $seq).

Also note that I used join - if you just print an array like this:

```
print @$seq;
```

it will print the contents of the array but it won't have commas between each element and there won't be a newline at the end.